# ModSecurity not enabled

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-security

I have similar problem like question [How do I enable mod_security in Ubuntu 10.04?](https://serverfault.com/questions/266044/how-do-i-enable-mod-security-in-ubuntu-10-04) , but i do not have the "minimal" file with me which i can replace and make it work.
My configuration is also different. here is my /etc/modsecurity/modsecurity.conf

```
    SecRuleEngine On
SecRequestBodyAccess On
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Content-Type "text/xml" \
     "phase:1,t:none,t:lowercase,pass,nolog,ctl:requestBodyProcessor=XML"
SecRequestBodyLimit 13107200
SecRequestBodyNoFilesLimit 131072
SecRequestBodyInMemoryLimit 131072
SecRequestBodyLimitAction Reject
SecRule REQBODY_ERROR "!@eq 0" \
"phase:2,t:none,log,deny,status:400,msg:'Failed to parse request body.',logdata:'%{reqbody_error_msg}',severity:2"
SecRule MULTIPART_STRICT_ERROR "!@eq 0" \
"phase:2,t:none,log,deny,status:44,msg:'Multipart request body \
failed strict validation: \
PE %{REQBODY_PROCESSOR_ERROR}, \
BQ %{MULTIPART_BOUNDARY_QUOTED}, \
BW %{MULTIPART_BOUNDARY_WHITESPACE}, \
DB %{MULTIPART_DATA_BEFORE}, \
DA %{MULTIPART_DATA_AFTER}, \
HF %{MULTIPART_HEADER_FOLDING}, \
LF %{MULTIPART_LF_LINE}, \
SM %{MULTIPART_SEMICOLON_MISSING}, \
IQ %{MULTIPART_INVALID_QUOTING}, \
IH %{MULTIPART_INVALID_HEADER_FOLDING}, \
IH %{MULTIPART_FILE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED}'"
SecRule MULTIPART_UNMATCHED_BOUNDARY "!@eq 0" \
"phase:2,t:none,log,deny,status:44,msg:'Multipart parser detected a possible unmatched boundary.'"
SecPcreMatchLimit 1000
SecPcreMatchLimitRecursion 1000
SecRule TX:/^MSC_/ "!@streq 0" \
        "phase:2,t:none,deny,msg:'ModSecurity internal error flagged: %{MATCHED_VAR_NAME}'"
SecResponseBodyAccess On
SecResponseBodyMimeType text/plain text/html text/xml
SecResponseBodyLimit 524288
SecResponseBodyLimitAction ProcessPartial
SecTmpDir /tmp/
SecDataDir /tmp/
SecUploadDir /opt/modsecurity/var/upload/
SecUploadKeepFiles RelevantOnly
SecUploadFileMode 0600
SecAuditEngine RelevantOnly
SecAuditLogRelevantStatus "^(?:5|4(?!04))"
SecAuditLogParts ABIJDEFHKZ
SecAuditLogType Serial
SecAuditLog /var/log/apache2/modsec_audit.log
SecAuditLogStorageDir /opt/modsecurity/var/audit/
SecArgumentSeparator &
SecCookieFormat 0
```

And my /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/modsecurity.conf is:

```
<IfModule security2_module>
    # Default Debian dir for modsecurity's persistent data
    SecDataDir /var/cache/modsecurity
 Include /usr/share/modsecurity-crs/base_rules/*conf
Include /usr/share/modsecurity-crs/modsecurity_crs_10_config.conf 
    # Include all the *.conf files in /etc/modsecurity.
    # Keeping your local configuration in that directory
    # will allow for an easy upgrade of THIS file and
    # make your life easier
    #Include "/etc/modsecurity/*.conf"
</IfModule>
```

and /usr/share/modsecurity-crs/modsecurity_crs_10_config.conf is :

```
SecComponentSignature "core ruleset/2.2.0"
SecRuleEngine On
SecDefaultAction "phase:2,deny,log"
SecAction "phase:1,id:'981207',t:none,nolog,pass, \
setvar:tx.critical_anomaly_score=5, \
setvar:tx.error_anomaly_score=4, \
setvar:tx.warning_anomaly_score=3, \
setvar:tx.notice_anomaly_score=2"
SecAction "phase:1,id:'981208',t:none,nolog,pass,setvar:tx.inbound_anomaly_score_level=5"
SecAction "phase:1,id:'981209',t:none,nolog,pass,setvar:tx.outbound_anomaly_score_level=4"
SecAction "phase:1,id:'981210',t:none,nolog,pass,setvar:tx.paranoid_mode=0"
SecAction "phase:1,id:'981211',t:none,nolog,pass,setvar:tx.max_num_args=255"
SecAction "phase:1,id:'981212',t:none,nolog,pass, \
setvar:'tx.allowed_methods=GET HEAD POST OPTIONS', \
setvar:'tx.allowed_request_content_type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded multipart/form-data text/xml application/xml application/x-amf', \
setvar:'tx.allowed_http_versions=HTTP/0.9 HTTP/1.0 HTTP/1.1', \
setvar:'tx.restricted_extensions=.asa/ .asax/ .ascx/ .axd/ .backup/ .bak/ .bat/ .cdx/ .cer/ .cfg/ .cmd/ .com/ .config/ .conf/ .cs/ .csproj/ .csr/ .dat/ .db/ .dbf/ .dll/ .dos/ .htr/ .htw/ .ida/ .idc/ .idq/ .inc/ .ini/ .key/ .licx/ .lnk/ .log/ .mdb/ .old/ .pass/ .pdb/ .pol/ .printer/ .pwd/ .resources/ .resx/ .sql/ .sys/ .vb/ .vbs/ .vbproj/ .vsdisco/ .webinfo/ .xsd/ .xsx/', \
setvar:'tx.restricted_headers=/Proxy-Connection/ /Lock-Token/ /Content-Range/ /Translate/ /via/ /if/'"
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Content-Type "text/xml" \
        "chain,phase:1,id:'981053',t:none,t:lowercase,pass,nolog"
        SecRule REQBODY_PROCESSOR "!@streq XML" "ctl:requestBodyProcessor=XML"
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:User-Agent "^(.*)$" "phase:1,id:'981217',t:none,pass,nolog,t:sha1,t:hexEncode,setvar:tx.ua_hash=%{matched_var}"
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:x-forwarded-for "^\b(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\b" "phase:1,id:'981225',t:none,pass,nolog,capture,setvar:tx.real_ip=%{tx.1}"
SecRule &TX:REAL_IP "!@eq 0" "phase:1,id:'981226',t:none,pass,nolog,initcol:global=global,initcol:ip=%{tx.real_ip}_%{tx.ua_hash}"
SecRule &TX:REAL_IP "@eq 0"  "phase:1,id:'981218',t:none,pass,nolog,initcol:global=global,initcol:ip=%{remote_addr}_%{tx.ua_hash}"
```

No malicious access is being blocked, even in log files it says there are critical alerts, but request is not being blocked.
i just want my requests to be blocked. what is wrong in configuration??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

was able to teak some settings, and correct usage of conf files made it work